# Abort message: 'couldn't find an OpenGL ES implementation'

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to run lollipop on my device and when I flashed the image i am getting i am getting the following log

```
--------- beginning of crash
F/libc    ( 1565): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 1565 (surfaceflinger)
I/DEBUG   ( 1572): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   ( 1572): Build fingerprint:     'Android/full_arndale/arndale:5.0.2/LRX22G/veera05211114:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   ( 1572): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   ( 1572): ABI: 'arm'
I/DEBUG   ( 1572): pid: 1565, tid: 1565, name: surfaceflinger  >>>     /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
I/DEBUG   ( 1572): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
I/DEBUG   ( 1572): Abort message: 'couldn't find an OpenGL ES implementation'
I/DEBUG   ( 1572):     r0 00000000  r1 0000061d  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1572):     r4 b6f34114  r5 00000006  r6 00000002  r7 0000010c
I/DEBUG   ( 1572):     r8 b6962000  r9 00000000  sl 00000000  fp beebfa9c
I/DEBUG   ( 1572):     ip 0000061d  sp beebf510  lr b6ebdf21  pc b6ee1858  cpsr 60070010
I/DEBUG   ( 1572): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1572): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   ( 1572):     #00 pc 0003a858  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
I/DEBUG   ( 1572):     #01 pc 00016f1d  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
I/DEBUG   ( 1572):     #02 pc 00017b2f  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
I/DEBUG   ( 1572):     #03 pc 0001439d  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
I/DEBUG   ( 1572):     #04 pc 00012a3c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
I/DEBUG   ( 1572):     #05 pc 00007a59  /system/lib/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+88)
I/DEBUG   ( 1572):     #06 pc 000430b9  /system/lib/libEGL.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1572):     #07 pc 00010641  /system/lib/libEGL.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1572):     #08 pc 00010e21  /system/lib/libEGL.so (eglGetDisplay+24)
I/DEBUG   ( 1572):     #09 pc 000171d5  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::init()+44)
I/DEBUG   ( 1572):     #10 pc 000007e1  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
I/DEBUG   ( 1572):     #11 pc 000128ed  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+44)
I/DEBUG   ( 1572):     #12 pc 000008d8  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
I/mediaserver( 1574): ServiceManager: 0xb60500c0
I/AudioFlinger( 1574): Using default 3000 mSec as standby time.
I/ServiceManager( 1574): Waiting for service batterystats...
I/DEBUG   ( 1572): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1572): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_00
 I/ServiceManager( 1563): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
```

I am unable to know what is wrong with the openGl?
Kitkat is running fine on my device when I tried lollipop i am getting this issue

Comment: Hi! I get the same problem with building AOSP. May you share your solution, thanks!

Comment: Hey, Just confirm that you have the GPU support in your AOSP.
In my case I dont have support for my board ie I am using arndale board. I dont have support for mali libraries as they stopped the supporting.

Comment: What you mean by "confirm that you have the GPU support". There is special options for building? I'm build on Nexus 10, so not board.

Comment: I mean does it have graphics libraries of the GPU that used in Nexus? Or else u need to implement software rendering ie bypassing the hardware gpu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is because no OpenGL ES libraries found in either /system/lib/egl or /vendor/lib/egl

Comment: Hi! How fix  it? Where get correct source, for adding?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to colordancer's answer, here is the **line** which reports the fatal error:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/android-7.0.0_r1/opengl/libs/EGL/Loader.cpp#229

This is due to it not finding *EGL ES libs* in the /vendor or the /system partition.

Currently,

```
libEGL.so
libGLESv2.so
libGLESv1_CM.so
```

These are the available EGL ES libs for Android.

**Solution:** 
Simply find the file from the stock rom and put it in the ROM and check if it proceeds. If yes, you can add it to the vendor prebuilts. If not, there might be some other issue

**Notes**
Currently on my OnePlus 2, running my halogenOS build, has the following stuff:

In **/vendor**

```
root@:/vendor # busybox find . | grep egl                                  
./lib/egl
./lib/egl/eglSubDriverAndroid.so
./lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
./lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
./lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
./lib/egl/libQTapGLES.so
./lib/egl/libq3dtools_adreno.so
./lib/egl/libq3dtools_esx.so
./lib64/egl
./lib64/egl/eglSubDriverAndroid.so
./lib64/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
./lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
./lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
./lib64/egl/libQTapGLES.so
./lib64/egl/libq3dtools_adreno.so
./lib64/egl/libq3dtools_esx.so
```

And, in **/system**

```
root@:/system # find . | grep egl
./app/Gallery2/lib/arm64/libjni_eglfence.so
./lib64/libjni_eglfence.so
./vendor/lib/egl
./vendor/lib/egl/eglSubDriverAndroid.so
./vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
./vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
./vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
./vendor/lib/egl/libQTapGLES.so
./vendor/lib/egl/libq3dtools_adreno.so
./vendor/lib/egl/libq3dtools_esx.so
./vendor/lib64/egl
./vendor/lib64/egl/eglSubDriverAndroid.so
./vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
./vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
./vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
./vendor/lib64/egl/libQTapGLES.so
./vendor/lib64/egl/libq3dtools_adreno.so
./vendor/lib64/egl/libq3dtools_esx.so
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Download corresponding hardware drivers, especially the GPU's which provides egl implementations such as `libGLESv2_andreno.so, libGLESv2.so...`, and extract the binaries into your AOSP directory.

Reference link: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers

2) Rebuild Android system image

> make -j8

3) Erase data and burn your image onto device

> fastboot -w
>
> fastboot flashall

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you didn't include the required proprietary libraries.

Please follow the instructions from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33083512/aosp-6-0-build-for-hammerhead-proprietary-binaries/39927763#39927763) to download specific libraries. After then, put the binaries in the root directory of your AOSP source project and execute

```
make clobber && make -j4
```

Then you are good to go.