# AOSP not booting on Nexus 5

Tags: android, android-source, nexus-5

I am trying to boot my Nexus 5 hammerhead device with the Android Source code(android-5.1.1_r3). The following are the steps I followed:

- $ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-5.1.1_r3
- repo sync

After this I downloaded the following binaries for android-5.1.1_r3 (LMY48B)

- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/broadcom-hammerhead-lmy48b-2d0a908d.tgz
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/lge-hammerhead-lmy48b-92cca4b9.tgz
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/qcom-hammerhead-lmy48b-021b52eb.tgz

Next I untarred the binaries and executed the scripts and accepted the license. This added all the required files in the vendors folder.

Next, I ran the following commands:

- source build/envsetup.sh
- lunch aosp_hammerhead-userdebug
- make -j24

Lastly, I flashed my device with the images in the out folder.

- fastboot oem unlock
- fastboot flash boot out/target/product/hammerhead/boot.img
- fastboot flash system out/target/product/hammerhead/system.img
- fastboot flash recovery out/target/product/hammerhead/recovery.img
- fastboot reboot

Everything goes fine up till here. But now when the device reboots, it gets stuck in the Google Logo. I am able to take the shell access with adb shell though. I checked a lot of similar questions but now I have incorporated everything that I had missed. Still no luck. Any hints how to proceed from here?

**EDIT**

I am getting the following Logs in the adb logcat.

```
I/mediaserver(10342): ServiceManager: 0xb61500c0
I/AudioFlinger(10342): Using default 3000 mSec as standby time.
I/ServiceManager(10342): Waiting for service batterystats...
I/DEBUG   (  167): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  167): Build fingerprint: 'Android/aosp_hammerhead/hammerhead:5.0/LRX21O/bhatia04291114:userdebug/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  167): Revision: '11'
I/DEBUG   (  167): ABI: 'arm'
I/DEBUG   (  167): pid: 10341, tid: 10341, name: surfaceflinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
I/DEBUG   (  167): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
I/DEBUG   (  167): Abort message: 'couldn't find an OpenGL ES implementation'
I/DEBUG   (  167):     r0 00000000  r1 00002865  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  167):     r4 b6fe8114  r5 00000006  r6 00000002  r7 0000010c
I/DEBUG   (  167):     r8 b6a62000  r9 00000000  sl 00000000  fp bef19afc
I/DEBUG   (  167):     ip 00002865  sp bef19570  lr b6f72af9  pc b6f965f0  cpsr 60070010
I/DEBUG   (  167): 
I/DEBUG   (  167): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  167):     #00 pc 0003a5f0  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
I/DEBUG   (  167):     #01 pc 00016af5  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
I/DEBUG   (  167):     #02 pc 00017707  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
I/DEBUG   (  167):     #03 pc 00013f75  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
I/DEBUG   (  167):     #04 pc 00012a3c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
I/DEBUG   (  167):     #05 pc 00007a59  /system/lib/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+88)
I/DEBUG   (  167):     #06 pc 000430b9  /system/lib/libEGL.so
I/DEBUG   (  167):     #07 pc 00010641  /system/lib/libEGL.so
I/DEBUG   (  167):     #08 pc 00010e21  /system/lib/libEGL.so (eglGetDisplay+24)
I/DEBUG   (  167):     #09 pc 000171e5  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so (android::SurfaceFlinger::init()+44)
I/DEBUG   (  167):     #10 pc 000007e1  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
I/DEBUG   (  167):     #11 pc 000128ed  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+44)
I/DEBUG   (  167):     #12 pc 000008d8  /system/bin/surfaceflinger
D/AndroidRuntime(10344): 
D/AndroidRuntime(10344): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(10344): CheckJNI is OFF
I/art     (10344): option[0]=-Xzygote
I/art     (10344): option[1]=-Xstacktracefile:/data/anr/traces.txt
I/art     (10344): option[2]=exit
I/art     (10344): option[3]=vfprintf
I/art     (10344): option[4]=sensitiveThread
I/art     (10344): option[5]=-verbose:gc
I/art     (10344): option[6]=-Xms8m
I/art     (10344): option[7]=-Xmx512m
I/art     (10344): option[8]=-XX:mainThreadStackSize=24K
I/art     (10344): option[9]=-XX:HeapGrowthLimit=192m
I/art     (10344): option[10]=-XX:HeapMinFree=512k
I/art     (10344): option[11]=-XX:HeapMaxFree=8m
I/art     (10344): option[12]=-XX:HeapTargetUtilization=0.75
I/art     (10344): option[13]=-Xgenregmap
I/art     (10344): option[14]=-Xgc:precise
I/art     (10344): option[15]=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_android_adb,suspend=n,server=y
I/art     (10344): option[16]=-Xlockprofthreshold:500
I/art     (10344): option[17]=-Ximage-compiler-option
I/art     (10344): option[18]=--runtime-arg
I/art     (10344): option[19]=-Ximage-compiler-option
I/art     (10344): option[20]=-Xms64m
I/art     (10344): option[21]=-Ximage-compiler-option
I/art     (10344): option[22]=--runtime-arg
I/art     (10344): option[23]=-Ximage-compiler-option
I/art     (10344): option[24]=-Xmx64m
I/art     (10344): option[25]=-Ximage-compiler-option
I/art     (10344): option[26]=--image-classes-zip=/system/framework/framework.jar
I/art     (10344): option[27]=-Ximage-compiler-option
I/art     (10344): option[28]=--image-classes=preloaded-classes
I/art     (10344): option[29]=-Xcompiler-option
I/art     (10344): option[30]=--runtime-arg
I/art     (10344): option[31]=-Xcompiler-option
I/art     (10344): option[32]=-Xms64m
I/art     (10344): option[33]=-Xcompiler-option
I/art     (10344): option[34]=--runtime-arg
I/art     (10344): option[35]=-Xcompiler-option
I/art     (10344): option[36]=-Xmx512m
I/art     (10344): option[37]=-Duser.language=en
I/art     (10344): option[38]=-Duser.region=US
I/SamplingProfilerIntegration(10344): Profiling disabled.
D/Zygote  (10344): begin preload
I/DEBUG   (  167): 
I/DEBUG   (  167): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_07
I/ServiceManager(  160): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
E/sdcard  (  175): missing packages.list; retrying
E/sdcard  (  175): missing packages.list; retrying
I/Netd    (10466): Netd 1.0 starting
E/QCOMKeyMaster(10470): failed to load qseecom library
E/keystore(10470): could not open keymaster device in keystore (Operation not permitted)
E/keystore(10470): keystore keymaster could not be initialized; exiting
I/SurfaceFlinger(10468): SurfaceFlinger is starting
I/SurfaceFlinger(10468): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
```

Basically the same logs keep repeating.

Comment: @0X0nosugar Even I was a little confused but I saw similar questions asked on this forum, so I posted it here.

Comment: Anyways, why is my question downvoted?

Comment: I have not downvoted it but as said above this question doesn't belong to this site

Comment: attach boot adb logcat, if it's available. Maybe you have missed something

Comment: Wasn't me and I've learned not to expect those who do to explain why. Just been over to android.stackexchange but they on the other hand don't seem to like questions about AOSP (one [question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/141573) closed "migration rejected") So good luck with your problem!

Comment: @Vivek Mishra - please note I did not "say", I asked because I wasn't sure about it. In fact I was going to flag as off-topic but then didn't.

Comment: @0X0nosugar This is off topic and this does belong to android.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AnkurBhatia Why did you choose to flash each image independently rather than using `fastboot -w flashall` like the instructions say to: https://source.android.com/source/building.html#flash-a-device ? Note that the '-w' wipes data/cache which can cause issues if you don't wipe when flashing sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @odexcide. Actually I tried it first with that, however it didn't work. Then I looked for some similar questions and found this. I performed the same process again and it finally worked. :) Still could not locate what I missed in the first place.

Comment: @VivekMishra I have seen similar questions asked in this forum and as 0x0nugar shared, a similar question was rejected by android.stackexchange.com. Please check the link he mentioned in one of the above comments. Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to say try asking this question on Android Enthusiast site you can get better response there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you missed downloading proprietary binaries for your device. 
check [this  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39927763/6030201)

Comment: Yes @Ayham. That was the case.The binaries I downloaded were not the correct ones.